# Concentric circles evenly spaced in UV mode

Tags: uv

My model is a simple UV sphere made of 128 segments and 128 rings.
[image: model]
My UV map is made of a plain disc with concentric circles.
[image: uv map]
I would like to evenly space the circles (with a constant offset). How can I achieve this without taking care of the circles one by one ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you please upload an image with your uv map and your model?

Comment: Here is my UV layout.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that this is something like a somewhat flattened sphere or a bevelled cylinder?

Comment: Do you know the number of rings / segments? If so its pretty much a map of `u, v = r * sin(a), r * cos(a)` Agree with @xlxs that an image of model / map would be handy.

Comment: Here is my model.

Answer (score 1):

ok the answer was pretty hard to find :P so what you basically wana do is to have a uv consist of concentric circles .This could be done if you select all the **inner rings** except the vertice at the mid of the concentric uv map and smooth them.But this can't be done in blender..... So what I did was to create 2 shape keys a key with the original mesh and an other one in which I smooth out all the inner rings (except the vertice in the center of the mesh).Then Uv unwram it and change the shape key value and you got it ! (I will upload a blend file with an exaple)
Also be sure to set the options so you achieve maximum smoothness 
[image]

Edit: If you have many edje rings and dont want to select them by hand you can do
this:
[image]

So what you can do to select the rings is:Create a new shape key and transform your mesh similar to mines*(orange arrow) (note the **red** circle options) .Then do the options that are pointed with pink (you should change to ejde select mode purple) and after you click the option that the pink arrow is pointing you will have **ALL** the edje rings selected.

*What I did was to grab the midle vertice and pull it up

Comment: Does it work???

Comment: Also in your example it might be time consuming to select all the inner rings (except the midle vertice) but thats an other question:P

Comment: Thank you. My model has many rings, actually many more than the example I have posted... I am looking for a more automated solution.

Comment: @Numid I'm editing the answer .I will add how to select the rings.

Comment: Added if its still cofused dont hesitate to ask :P

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to use the *Data Transfer* modifier for this. For this to work, the vertex and/or face creation order seems to be important, so you can't just use a simpler mesh that you subdivide. However, the *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* addon saves the day.

Enable the addon by going to user preferences, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> or *File -> User Preferences*, click the *Add-ons* tab, click *Add Mesh* and make sure the checkbox next to *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* is checked. If you want the changes to persist, click *Save User Preferences*. Then close the window.

[image]

Now click *Add -> Mesh -> Math Function -> XYZ Math Surface* or press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd>. For the parameters add the following.

*X equation*
`cos(u)*(1-fabs(v))`

*Y equation*
`sin(u)*(1-fabs(v))`

*Z equation*
`v`

*U min*
`0`

*U max*
`2*pi`

*U step*
The number of segments you need.

*V min*
`-1`

*V max*
`1`

*V step*
The number of rings you need.

Enable *U wrap* and disable *V wrap* and *Close V*.

I'm not going to go into too deep an explanation of the math here, but basically this is a modified version of the parametric equations for a [sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere#Equations_in_three-dimensional_space), which generates a [bicone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicone), which can be unwrapped and the UV map then be transfered to a regular UV sphere, and the creation order of the vertices and faces will match the UV sphere, so the data transfer works correctly.

[image]

Your UV map looks like it's projected from view, so that's what I'll show here.
<kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode and make sure everything is selected. If it isn't already, press <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice, until it is. Remove double vertices, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>D</kbd> or *Mesh -> Vertices -> Remove Doubles*. Go into top view by pressing <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> or clicking *View -> Top*. Then press <kbd>U</kbd> followed by <kbd>B</kbd> or click *Mesh -> UV Unwrap -> Project from View (Bounds)*.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> back into object mode. Add a UV sphere, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd> followed by <kbd>U</kbd> or *Add -> Mesh -> UV Sphere*. Give it the same number of segments and rings as the bicone. Go to the modifiers tab and add a *Data Transfer* modifier. Set *Source Object* to the bicone. Enable *Face Corner Data* and set it to *Nearest Face Interpolated*. Enable UVs. Set *Face Data* to *Nearest Face*. Click _Generate Data Layers. Apply the modifier.

[image]

Now you can safely delete the bicone, or you can reuse it for several spheres. Select the sphere and go to the UV editor to check the UV map, which should look something like this.

[image]